# Store text file content in sqlite3 database

Tags: c, sqlite

I'm trying to store the content from text files into sqlite3 using C. I tried `sqlite3_exec()` in combination with `readfile()` but get the error message:

> "Error: no such function: readfile"

```
#include <sqlite3.h>

int main(void)
{
    sqlite3 *db;

    char *sqlcmd = calloc(1024, sizeof(char));

    sqlite3_open_v2("sql.db", &db, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE, NULL);

    sprintf(sqlcmd, "INSERT INTO records (data) VALUES (readfile('text.txt'));");

    sqlite3_exec(db, sqlcmd, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

I've also tried below code, but it fails at `sqlite3_step()` with :

> "Error: (null)"

```
#include <sqlite3.h>

int main(void)
{
    sqlite3 *db;
    sqlite3_stmt *stmt;

    char *sqlcmd = calloc(1024, sizeof(char));

    sqlite3_open_v2("sql.db", &db, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE, NULL);

    sprintf(sqlcmd, "INSERT INTO records (data) VALUES (readfile('text.txt'));");

    sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sqlcmd, 0, &stmt, NULL);

    sqlite3_step(stmt);

    sqlite3_finalize(stmt);

    return 0;
}
```

I've tried to use sqlite3ext.h but that fails at `sqlite3_open_v2()`.

```
#include <sqlite3ext.h>

SQLITE_EXTENSION_INIT1

int main(void)
{
    sqlite3 *db;


    char *sqlcmd = calloc(1024, sizeof(char));

    sqlite3_open_v2("sql.db", &db, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE, NULL);

    sprintf(sqlcmd, "INSERT INTO records (data) VALUES (readfile('text.txt'));");

    sqlite3_exec(db, sqlcmd, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

I can use `sqlite3_exe()` with stmt to add data without issues. It's only `readfile()` that fails. Using the command inside sqlcmd directly in the sqlite3 database works fine.

Comment: You have to load (and first compile) the appropriate sqlite extension module to get `readfile()`. See the last paragraph of https://sqlite.org/cli.html#file_i_o_functions

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).